# Is there a way to change Antd internal button's color?

Tags: css, button, antd

I am using antd for my app. I need to change the color of a default Primary Button from Blue to Grey. It seems like antd doesn't provide such an option. How can I change the button color easily?

Comment: Add you code ... here

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The formal solution by `antd` is the `style` props as mentioned on every component's API:

```js
<Button type="primary" style={{ background: "red", borderColor: "yellow" }}>
  Submit
</Button>;
```

Moreover, when you want to override the style for every component in your application, you should override the CSS class or [Customize Theme](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) as mentioned.

```
// Should be used for overriding all buttons.
// Import the css on entry point.
.ant-btn-primary {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Also, note that you can style the button's container and target its color (Without affecting the whole application styling):

```
.button-container {
  .ant-btn-primary {
    background-color: palevioletred;
  }
}
```

An example with CSS-in-JS:

```
const ButtonContainer = styled.div`
  .ant-btn-primary {
    background-color: red;
  }
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ButtonContainer>
      <Button type="primary">My Button</Button>
    </ButtonContainer>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit quizzical-chatterjee-8vp4v]

Comment: As I said, I'm unfamiliar with antd and their best practices. Although, if he wants to set all of his primary button colors to a specific color, then I think it would be unwise to do so as inline-style. In fact, I'm not a fan of inline-style because of SOC & DRY. We have stylesheets for that.

Answer (score 6):

I'm unfamiliar with Ant Design, but you can see in their docs ([Customize Theme](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme)) that you're able to edit the primary color like so:

```
@primary-color: #1890ff; // primary color for all components
```

In case you want to change only the button's color, you can create a new var:

```
@button-color: #757575; // a custom variable
```

and then add a rule (which will override the source):

```
.ant-btn-primary {
    background-color: @button-color;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works for me. By the way, I feel this is kind of a workaround by manipulating CSS. If Antd can provide a formal solution, that will be great.

Comment: @Dong not really. a workaround. In case you want to maintain the primary color but change the primary color of buttons specifically, it wouldn't be conventional. In case you want to change both primary color and the button's primary color, you could just modify the variable `@primary-color` (which is what they tell.you to do in their docs.

Answer (score 6):

## Best practice for Ant Design 5.x

According to the latest doc, it's best practice to use `ConfigProvider`:

```
<ConfigProvider
    theme={{
      token: {
        colorPrimary: '#00b96b',
      },
    }}
  >
    <Button />
</ConfigProvider>
```

Ref: https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#customize-design-token

[image]

Comment: If you're using Tailwind Css along with Antd this solution would probably not work because of a CSS conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modular way in **Antd v5** that reuses your theme colors honoring dark mode, extending Tyler's answer.

```js
import { ConfigProvider, Button, theme } from 'antd';
const { useToken } = theme;

const ColorButton = ({children, override, ...props}) => {
    const { token, algorithm } = useToken();
    const overrideColor = token[override] || override;
    const modifiedTheme = {
        token: {...token, colorPrimary: overrideColor},
        algorithm: algorithm,
    };

    return (
        <ConfigProvider theme={modifiedTheme} >
            <Button {...props}>{children}</Button>
        </ConfigProvider>
    );
};

export default ColorButton;
```

You can now use use it like so:

```
<ColorButton type="primary" override="colorSuccess">Green</ColorButton>
<ColorButton override="colorWarning">Orange</ColorButton>
<ColorButton shape="round" override="#e517ff">Custom</ColorButton>
```